# AngularDart async pipe not working with dotted notation

Tags: html, angular, dart, angular-dart

**EDIT: I am using AngularDart 5 and i have created an issue on GitHub https://github.com/dart-lang/angular/issues/1311**

I have got this AngularDart Component:

```
@Component(
    selector: 'todo-list',
    template: '<div>{{todos | async}}</div>',
    directives: [coreDirectives],
    pipes: const [AsyncPipe])
class TodoListComponent {
  Stream<List<TodoItem>> todos =
      new TodoListViewModelImpl(new TodoServiceImpl()).output.todoItems;
}
```

[image]

As you can see, this is working like expected. The template displays an empty list, because there has not todo item been inserted yet.

However i do not want to have a `todos` attribute to access `output.todoItems`. 
I want to access `output.todoItems` directly from the template using dotted notation:

```
@Component(
    selector: 'todo-list',
    template: '<div>{{viewModel.output.todoItems | async}}</div>',
    directives: [coreDirectives],
    pipes: const [AsyncPipe])
class TodoListComponent {
  TodoListViewModel viewModel =
      new TodoListViewModelImpl(new TodoServiceImpl());
}
```

BUT this does not work actually. I dont get any error messages whatsoever.

[image]

Comment: try using `{{viewModel?.output?.todoItems | async}}`

Comment: What Dart and AngularDart version are you using? I think this should just work. Haven't seen issues like this mentioned.

Comment: @PardeepJain not woking unfortunately :(

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer AngularDart 5  newest release, because i need Dart 2 support

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in your code. Might be a bug. I'd create a bug report in the AngularDart repo (please add a link to the issue here and a link to the SO question in the issue to have them crosslinked).